# How to check checkbox on pageload

Tags: html

Here is my code below. I don't know why each time I got to the page, it doesn't load with the checkbox checked. I've tried checked="yes" and checked = "true". Nothing works.

```
<TR>
 <cfif request.collectEnableStatusNotesCheckbox>
  <TD colspan="2">
   <input type="Checkbox" name="status" value="1" checked /> Add Status
  </TD>
 </cfif>
</TR>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be `checked="checked"` or just short `checked`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="status" value="1" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="status" value="1" checked="checked">
```

& the type should be `checkbox`, not `Checkbox`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think that the type was case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Your following code line is correct.

```
<TD colspan="2"><input type="Checkbox" name="status" value="1" checked /> Add Status</TD>
```

Try it on jsfiddle, it works. 
Please check if your if condition is getting satisfied.
Also, IE might give you problem with checked, try checked="checked" there.

Thanks!